# Run maven web application from command line

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run my maven web application through:

```
java -jar CliniKeyMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

First, I faced the error no main manifest attribute in CliniKeyMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and after searching for a quite long time I reached this in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>manifest</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and this is the App.java that contains a main:

```
package com.mycompany.clinikeymaven;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

But I'm now facing the error:

> Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App

When I run the application from the NetBeans it is working but I need to run it from the command line.. what should I do?

Comment: Are you aware that this is not how web applications usually work? Unless you're using something like [wildfly-swarm](https://github.com/wildfly-swarm) you need to `deploy` your WAR file into a Java EE application server which then directs web requests to it. There is no `main` method.

Comment: Yeah I already did this but I just put this main method as a recommendation from other people to try running the WAR file without facing the error I mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a working pom .Pls try this one.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to user the [Maven jar plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) and not the [Maven war plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <compress>true</compress>
            <index>true</index>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also as people said in the comments, with the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) you are creating a .war file that needs an application server to be deployed on in order to run. 

For example the generating .war could be deployed on in tomcat server.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`java -cp CliniKeyMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App`

Alternately, you can update the content of your manifest file to following:

`Main-Class: com.mycompany.clinikeymaven.App`

Then you can try running it the following way:

`java -jar CliniKeyMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

Comment: Already tried both and I still get the "could not load or find main" error

Comment: The OP's very first line says `I'm trying to run my maven web application...`. This is not how you run a web application.

Comment: @SteveC, you might want to read OP's question again. He wants to run the main class (class with the main method) which is packaged in a war file.

Comment: You solution is unlikely to help him solve his CNFE because a WAR file's dependencies are packaged as jars embedded in it's WEB-INF/lib directory. Classes in these jars will be invisible to this main class because it is not being loaded by a servlet container's class loader. The uncredited advice that he received to add a "main" method in order to "run" the "web application" is flawed.